ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version' error with buildozer debuging (openCV+mediapipe+tensorflow)

this is where my python and pip,make sure they are in same place

jack@04272:~/Sign_apk$ which python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
jack@04272:~/Sign_apk$ which pip3.9
/usr/local/bin/pip3.9

#Error
[INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for kivy[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/jack/Sign_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_24/kivy/kivy
[DEBUG]:   -> running python3.9 -c import _version; print(_version.__version__)
[DEBUG]:    Traceback (most recent call last):
[DEBUG]:      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
[DEBUG]:    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'
Exception in thread background thread for pid 9009:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -c 'import _version; print(_version.__version__)'

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'
  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/local/bin/python3.9', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3==3.11.6,kivy==1.9.0,tensorflow==2.16.1,opencv-python==4.9.0.80,mediapipe==0.10.11,openpyxl==3.1.2', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/jack/Sign_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=24', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/04272:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2395,unix/04272:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2395'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_CA:en'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'lzh_TW'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_NAME = 'lzh_TW'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'lzh_TW'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/jack/Sign_apk'
#     LOGNAME = 'jack'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'wayland'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '2395'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.SJFJM2'
#     HOME = '/home/jack'
#     USERNAME = 'jack'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LC_PAPER = 'lzh_TW'
#     LANG = 'en_CA.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6800'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/e1b44003_0abe_4fde_b39b_4ac095a86a41'
#     GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY = ':1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'lzh_TW'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'jack'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.169'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'lzh_TW'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'lzh_TW'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=fb590673bdeea512d4f27f90662d1176'
#     PAPERSIZE = 'a4'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'lzh_TW'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/jack/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/jack/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/jack/.local/bin/'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=fb590673bdeea512d4f27f90662d1176'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'lzh_TW'
#     _ = '/home/jack/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/jack/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/jack/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/jack/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

this is mine requirement in buildozer.spec
requirements = python3==3.11.6,kivy==1.9.0,tensorflow==2.16.1,opencv-python==4.9.0.80,mediapipe==0.10.11,openpyxl==3.1.2`
and after i run buildozer -v android debug this happend
I've retried install ubuntu(ubuntu 22.04) many times(i use VirtualBox).Its pretty frustrated to get this error everytime.And i am new to linux and English,learning from beginning!

add pillow in the requirements and try again.

@Tan Same error after i put pillow=10.2.0 in kivy requirement and run buildozer -v android debug, It happens while applying patches for kivy[armeabi-v7a]

It would be best to use a debugging tool to see what errors occur, when you run the app on your phone. here is a link to a YouTube video that might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBgkCcPsx1Y&ab_channel=NilegProduction
